# OpenCV 2.2 with Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, opencv

I'm working with program that is based on this example: http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Opencv+webcam+viewer?content=89995. When I try to use Microsoft Lifecam HD-5000 or Lifecam Vx-2000 in Windows 7 I get black image, but in Windows XP the Vx-2000 works, I haven't had chance to test the HD 5000 in it yet.

However I get working image in Windows 7 when I use old Creative vf-0040 camera.
This is how the camera is created

```
CvCapture *camera;
camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
assert(camera);
IplImage * image=cvQueryFrame(camera);
assert(image);
```

And image is taken:

```
IplImage *image=cvQueryFrame(camera);
image=cvQueryFrame(camera);
```

I would appreciate any advice with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the latest svn version of opencv using tortoise svn. The release of opencv 2.2 did not work on my machine's webcam either, but the newest svn did. You will have to build this version yourself using cmake. As a side note, so long as you're building it you might as well download TBB from intel and add that into your build for a nice 4x speed up of face detection among other functions.

Comment: Did this work for you? I also have a LifeCam HD 5000 and only get a black screen (using windows build of OpenCV2.2 release)... I just tried building the SVN version which crashes during make for me... would be great if you could tell me if and how you solved this problem

Comment: Well, assuming it didn't crash during make it would work for you too. I assume by crashing you mean it got errors? To build it, there is a youtube video on how to build opencv with tbb. One other quick thing you can do to get it working, is just use the pre-built 2.1 version.

Comment: with the 2.1 version you got the webcam working? Then why doesn't it work with the 2.2 release but it does with the 2.2 svn? Weird... and yes with crashing I meant it got errors in make (with highguy/libVideoInput)...

Comment: The 2.2 SVN is a different and updated version than the 2.2 release. My advice, try getting it working with 2.1. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I just tried compiling the 2.1 release and I get the exact same error as with the 2.2 SVN version... 2.2 release works fine though...